# Save in UTC and display in local time with momentjs

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a form where the use can save a schedule date. I want to be able to send to my backedn the date to utc format. I have something like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="scheduled_publication[publication_date]" value="2015/11/27">
<input type="hidden" name="scheduled_publication[time]" value="13:00">
```

But the problem is if I change this value with the browser timezone offset, I have also to change the date value sometimes. A schedule at 01am with -02:00 time offset will change the date. 
Does the easiest scenario is to get the two current values and process them with momentjs?

Other question. How to display the time with the correct timezone with momentjs. The raw date rendered looks like : `2015-11-16 16:47:29 +0100`. I've try using [`.utc` method](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

```
> moment('2015-11-16 16:47:29 +0100').format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY ha")
"Monday, November 16th 2015 4pm"
> moment.utc('2015-11-16 16:47:29 +0100').format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY ha")
"Monday, November 16th 2015 4pm" #should be 3pm
```

Why local is not applied on the first command ? When I do

```
> moment('2015-11-16 16:47:29 +0100')
Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2015-11-16 16:47:29 +0100", _isUTC: false, _locale: Locale, _d: Mon Nov 16 2015 16:47:29 GMT+0100 (CET)…}
```

Timezone seems to be recognised.

When you work with times at the end it's difficult to stay consitent.

**EDIT:**

With the comments and answer. First with the data insert by pickadate and pickatime with EST as computer time, I set the value (20 november at 23 hour) and convert them.

```
> var date = $("[name='scheduled_publication[publication_date]']").val()
> var time = $("[name='scheduled_publication[time]']").val()
> $("[name='scheduled_publication[time]']").val(moment(date + ' ' + time).toISOString())

[<input type=​"hidden" name=​"scheduled_publication[time]​" value=​"2015-11-18T14:​00:​00.000Z">​]
```

Except this quite ugly javascript. It seems good for me. The value return is in UTC. Perfect for my database.

Comment: Save and return in UTC Format (milliseconds since unix epoch will do). Its just that when displaying on a client, the local time zone (of the client machine), is automatically used to adjust the UTC date. You don't have to handle time-zones yourself, except in very specific cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So for display it's ok. I just need to manage to create a correct utc time from what the user insert.

Comment: You will have to know the pattern or parts of user input. See answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [ISO date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for storing dates on back-end:

```
moment().date(23).month('August').year(2015).hour(15).minute(45).second(0).millisecond(0).toISOString();
// output: 2015-08-23T10:15:00.000Z
```

or

```
moment('23 aug 2015, 3:45pm', 'DD MMM yyyy, hh:mma').toISOString();
// output: 2015-08-23T10:15:00.000Z
```

Notice that time-zone info got dropped (`Z` means its in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC)). Now, displaying it back:

```
moment('2015-08-23T10:15:00.000Z').toString(); 
// output: Sun Aug 23 2015 15:45:00 GMT+0230
```

You see ? `GMT+0230` got automatically there, because that's current machine's offset.

Formatted display:

```
moment('2015-08-23T10:15:00.000Z').format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY h:mma');
// output: Sunday, August 23rd 2015 3:45pm
```

Comment: hi @s-d thanks for your answer. I've edited my question with this tips of `.toISOString();` that is a nice method. If I can you feedback on what I did.